# Kineticjs export to jpeg fill transparent pixel with white?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, kineticjs

I want to export my Kineticjs stage with:

```
stage.toDataURL({
  mimeType : "image/jpeg",
  callback : function() {}
});
```

When I export this:

[image]

I get the following image after export:

[image]

All the transparent pixels are set to black.

**How can I set all the transparent pixel to white before exporting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

This occurs because on the KineticJS stage, the background is transparent: rgba(0,0,0,0).

The last zero in rgba is the alpha==the opacity.

But jpeg doesn't allow different opacities.  It only allows solid colors.

So when you save the stage with toDataURL, jpeg will make the background opacity a solid color == rgba(0,0,0,1).

```
rgba(0,0,0,1) is black.
```

Therefore, transparent pixels are always written as black when saving a jpeg.

**The solution**

Add a background rectangle that fills the stage with white (or other color) so jpeg will know which color to use for the background pixels.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/WZ5G2/

Comment: Could you post an example for your idea?